# How do I get a union type of all primitive types that are nested values of an object?

Tags: typescript, types

I need all primitive types (plus null) used inside of an object.

All answers, I found so far, were only for simple objects. But the ones I have are deeply nested and have arrays with objects in them.

For example for this object:

```
const Data = {
  a: {
    x: "foo",
  },
  b: {
    x: [123, 45],
    y: [
      {
        x: null,
      },
      { x: Symbol(666) },
    ],
  },
};
```

I try to derive the type (string | number | null | symbol)

```
type foo = DERIVE<typeof Data>    // foo = string | number | null | symbol
```

What I found so far on SO got me this far (which is a complete mess, sorry):

```
type RecursiveValues<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]:
  (T[Prop] extends Array<any> ? RecursiveValues<T[Prop][number]> : T[Prop] extends object
    ? RecursiveValues<T[Prop]>
    : T[Prop])
}[keyof T]
type TestValues = RecursiveValues<typeof Data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two hard things about this.

1. The type needs to recursive to drill into all the leaves
2. Array needs to specially handled because `keyof unknown[]` will include the methods that an array has.

You want something like this:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | symbol | null | undefined | ((...args: any[]) => any)

type DERIVE<T> =
  T extends Primitive ? T
  : T extends readonly unknown[] ? DERIVE<T[number]>
  : DERIVE<T[keyof T]>
```

Here the `Primitive` type exists to know when to stop drilling in. If these types are encountered, then the recursion stops. You will need to customize this list with the values that you are looking to end with.

Now we can go to the `DERIVE` type itself. Let's go line by line:

- `T extends Primitive ? T` If the type is a primitive, return it. Else continue.
- `: T extends readonly unknown[] ? DERIVE<T[number]>` If the type is an array, derive the type of it's members. Else continue.
- `: DERIVE<T[keyof T]>` The other checks failed, so we assume this is an object type and derive each property type of `T`.

This now works as you expect:

```
type Foo = DERIVE<typeof Data> // string | number | null | symbol
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgQygmBeGBvAUDGCBcmOuMAHoQEQBmIIFANMQL6O4BGh2JZhA2gIwAmAMz0YAFgCsAXVYkAnn2Lcu3EuRhgArgBsdc7i2UkMPGAGV5AWzYgdACgBszgJQwj3Wc0ZMYAbiwsKHkABwBTGAAFACcASytYqFiANwj0aDiwAHMYAB9NLRsw6LyYWzswhDBSiGtbHVLtPVKtMAATMKpYsDC20vt7ADphhGisiEIq+V5pN1QAPjwweRdA4PD4AFEAJQBJADVNgB4AFUXUYhOYMNIoMPaIKLiEpNSYAH4YE+JCK5u7h4waKVNrgHTyGCtADWYBAAHcwDMPls9odTrxtEVotJ5j8UQdjideFCwvIQFQvji1qEIgAxWhofFo9ZhcnwJAIRYAei5MAy3Ry+UxbGKjV0DXytRsdiwPJIAD13kA)

Comment: This breaks for readonly arrays. Always use `extends readonly T[]` to account for them.

Comment: Indeed, you're right! Thanks @zenly

Answer (score 1):

```
type primitive = string | number | boolean | symbol | null | undefined | bigint | Function
type DERIVE<T> = 
  | T extends primitive ? T
  : DERIVE<T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? T[number] : T[keyof T]>
```

Note that you may want to define your object `as const` if you want your values to be literals